# Pre_Get_Posts not sorting category posts based on custom field (price)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have been having weird problem with the below code. For some reason (beyond my understanding) pre_get_posts() just does not seem to be sorting the posts based on custom fields. Any idea on what could be the problem? Below is my pre_get_post() function code from functions.php.

```
function alter_main_query($query) {
    if (is_admin()){
        return;
    }
    if ($query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $SortType = 1;
        if(isset($_POST["sorttype"])) {
             $SortType = $_POST["sorttype"];
        }

        //default sorting is by availability in no of stores
        if ($SortType == 0) {
            $meta_query = array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'Lowest',
                    'value' => 0,
                    'compare' => '>'
                )
            );          
            $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query );            
            $query->set('meta_key', 'NoOfStoresAvailable');
            $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
            $query->set('order', 'DESC');

        } else if ($SortType == 1) {

            $meta_query = array(    
                array(
                    'key' => 'Lowest',
                    'value' => 0,
                    'compare' => '>'
                )
            );

            $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'Lowest' );            
            $query->set( 'order', 'DESC');  

        } else if ($SortType == 2) {
            $meta_query = array(    
                array(
                    'key' => 'Lowest',
                    'value' => 0,
                    'compare' => '>'
                )
            );

            $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'Lowest' );            
            $query->set( 'order', 'ASC');   

        } else if ($SortType == 3) {
            $meta_query = array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'Lowest',
                    'value' => 0,
                    'compare' => '>'
                )
            );
            $query->set('meta_key', 'AvgRatings');
            $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
            $query->set('order', 'DESC');           
        }

    }
    return $query;

}
```

Note: I have a dropdown on the site that allows the user to chose what he/she wishes to sort by (1=price high to low, 2=price low to high, 3=avg. ratings) and the selected sort value is passed through a form using post method. And if no value is passed, it will default to sorttype = 0 in the above function.

And the strange thing is that it only works the first time for whatever the default sorttype is set to. After that it just appears to be sorting in some random fashion.

Have already spent more than 24 hours trying to solve this but efforts so far has been futile.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

can you first try to change this

```
$SortType = 1;
if(isset($_POST["sorttype"])) {
     $SortType = $_POST["sorttype"];
}
```

by this

```
if(isset($_POST["sorttype"]))
   {
     $SortType = $_POST["sorttype"];
   }
else
   {
     $SortType=1;
   }
```

Comment: Hello Evrard, didn't really get the difference between the two? Will appreciate if you could help me understand it? Also any idea on why pre_get_post() is not sorting properly?